# fullCalendar V3 : How to fix a column by day by color

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm working back on an old project where fullCalendar V3 has been used to organise the day of each technician. As you can see on the screen see below, the color are mixed. I tried different ways to get one color by column without success :(

Would someone confirm me if it's possible to get the result expected ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to organise strictly by colour no. If you want to organise the work strictly by technician in columns then you'd need the resource-aware version of the grid which requires the premium Scheduler plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are right I would like to organise stricly by technicien. I didn't think to search to the premium feature, I hope that it'll be available in the V3 version.

Comment: Yes it is available with V3, although it is very out of date now, it would be recommended to upgrade in order to get more features, better performance and many bug fixes

Comment: I already start to rewrite the code by including the V5 version, I need to update the actual site version. (480$ is really too expensive for me :( ) Do you know if, it's possible to get another view as this screen (https://ibb.co/JsCJ3wX) ?

Comment: Not using fullCalendar there isn't, sorry. Did you explore all the license options? Some types of project and site are eligible for a free license